# How to copy a heap object to preserve it from destroying?

Tags: c

I have an object allocated on the heap. The object will be destroyed from the heap, but I need to preserve it, preferably through copying it and saving the pointer to it.

**An example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Human
{
    int age;
    char sex;
    float height;
    float weight;
};

struct Human *human;

void create_human(int age, char sex, float height, float weight)
{
    struct Human *A = (struct Human *) malloc(sizeof(struct Human));
    A->age = age;
    A->sex = sex;
    A->height = height;
    A->weight = weight;

    // copy A and save the pointer to the copy in the global variable

    free(A);
}

int main()
{
    create_human(22, 'M', 1.90, 100.0);
    printf("Age: %d\tSex: %c\tHeight %.2f\tWeight %.2f\n", human->age, human->sex, human->height, human->weight);
}
```

Here I need to copy the object `A` points to and make `human` point to the copy.

Comment: You'd *return* a pointer, and *not free the Human* before you've finished using it.

Comment: Why not simply do `human = A` and then skip `free(A)`?

Comment: And better yet, *return* the pointer, and don't use global variables.

Comment: `The object will be destroyed from the heap` it will not destroy until you destroy it `free(A)`.

Comment: This is just an example I made. The API I'm using fetches some files for me but later destroys them and I need them preserved.

Comment: _And that API fetches some files_ you need to preserve the values that pointer pointing  not the `pointer`.

Comment: API gives me a pointer to files allocated on the heap. It frees them automatically when it exits the function in which they are fetched.

Comment: @kiranBiradar That's what I'm asking for.

Comment: Not directly related to your question: _"// copy A and save the pointer to the copy in the global variable"_: this is very bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
human = (struct Human *) malloc(sizeof(struct Human));
memcpy(human, A, sizeof(struct Human));
```

If there were pointers to other structs inside Human, this would be slightly more complex!

Edit:
More elegant solution suggested by StoryTeller in comments:

```
human = (struct Human *) malloc(sizeof(struct Human));
*human = *A;
```

Comment: Or maybe just...`*human = *A;`? Probably the same net result, but far clearer IMO

Comment: @StoryTeller, as Hanlon notes in the comments above, this is only an example. In reality, the Free happens outside of his control.

Comment: Note I did not suggest `human = A;`, but `*human = *A;`. You can assign structures in C just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want something like this:

- no more obscure copying into a global variable (avoid global variables whenever possible)
- no more cast for malloc
- `free` called once we're done with the created human and not before

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Human
{
    int age;
    char sex;
    float height;
    float weight;
};

struct Human *create_human(int age, char sex, float height, float weight)
{
    struct Human *A = malloc(sizeof(struct Human));  // no need to cast
    A->age = age;
    A->sex = sex;
    A->height = height;
    A->weight = weight;
    return A;
}

int main()
{
    struct Human *human = create_human(22, 'M', 1.90, 100.0);
    printf("Age: %d\tSex: %c\tHeight %.2f\tWeight %.2f\n", human->age, human->sex, human->height, human->weight);
    free(human);
}
```

If you absolutely want to copy your human into a global variable, you can still do it:

```
...
struct human *globalhuman;
...
int main()
{
    globalhuman = create_human(22, 'M', 1.90, 100.0);
    printf("Age: %d\tSex: %c\tHeight %.2f\tWeight %.2f\n", globalhuman ->age, globalhuman ->sex, globalhuman ->height, globalhuman ->weight);
    free(globalhuman );
}
```

Comment: Not what I asked for.